# simple cout then cin allowing whitespace example?

Tags: c++, stl

Looking for a simple getline example which works correctly.

I want to input something on the keyboard and assign it to a std::string, allowing for whitespace and tabs. The delimiter is the carriage return.

TIA,
Bert

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main() {
  std::string s;
  std::cout << "Enter a line: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, s);
  std::cout << "You typed this: " << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter a line: foo bar
You typed this: foo bar
```

Comment: You don't need  #include <ostream>

Comment: I thought it was technically required for operator<<, no?

Comment: iostream pulls in most of the required stuff :)

Comment: @rob you would #include <ostream> if you wanted the output operators but didn't need cin, cout et al. As cout is an ostream, iostream must include <ostream> itself.

Answer (score 1):

An important note: after you use std::cin:

```
cin >> myVar;
```

The trailing newline is NOT removed. You have to use getline twice

```
std::getline(std::cin, myString);
std::getline(std::cin, myString);
```

if you have previously extracted from cin, once for the newline, and once for the actual string. There are other ways to do this too.

Comment: But also note: cin >> ignores proceeding whitespace so it would not be affected by the newline.